# when echoing renamed file its showing single character

Tags: php, upload, echo, rename

I am slowly working on a image uploader, and wondering why when echoing my renamed files, its giving me a single character instead of the whole thing.
Any reason it would be doing that?
[image]

It does tho, successfully upload the image as a **phil_546d196082606.jpg** with a different number for each image

Here is my code

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['addpart'])) {

    $image = $_FILES['images']['tmp_name'];
    $name = $_POST['username'];
    $i     = 0;
    foreach ($image as $key) {
    $fileData = pathinfo(basename($_FILES["images"]["name"][$i]));
$fileName = $name .'_'. uniqid() . '.' . $fileData['extension'];

        move_uploaded_file($key, "image/" . $fileName);

        copy("image/" . $fileName, "image_thumbnail/" . $fileName);
        $i++;
    }
    echo 'Uploaded<br>';

$fileName1 = $fileName[0];
$fileName2 = $fileName[1];
$fileName3 = $fileName[2];

echo 'Main Image - '.$fileName1.'<br>';
echo 'Extra Image 1 - '.$fileName2.'<br>';
echo 'Extra Image 2 - '.$fileName3.'<br>';
    echo '<hr>';

}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$filename is a string and strings in php are arrays where each letter has an index $filename[o] is the first letter and so on.Use

```
$filename[]=$name .'_'. uniqid() . '.' . $fileData['extension'];
```

Comment: thank you very much, would I use the same string **$filename[0]** and **$filename[1]**, when inserting to different columns of a row?

Comment: @BrianCherdak I dont really understand the question but $filename[0] will contain the first name and so on.

Comment: when I upload the file to the database, for example a news post with multiple images, and I want to insert diffeent images into different columns as values, would I add the **[0]** and **[1]**?

Comment: @BrianCherdak if you want to insert the image name ,yes.Those `[]` just transform the variable into a proper array

Answer (score 1):

```
$fileName = $name .'_'. uniqid() . '.' . $fileData['extension'];
```

Filename is the string. It is : $name . number.

Like philip12345.

So if we have:

```
philip
012345

$fileName[0] = p
$fileName[1] = h
```

Also you overwrite filename in each loop. Try to save it to an array and print it, here is some code:

```
$fileNames = array();

foreach ($image as $key) 
{
 $fileName = $name .'_'. uniqid() . '.' . $fileData['extension'];    
 fileNames[$i] = $fileName;
}

echo $fileNames[0];
echo $fileNames[1];
echo $fileNames[2];
```

You could also use a foreach loop to go over the array with the filenames and print each element, this is cool because it will works with any number of images, not just 3:

```
foreach ($fileNames AS $key2)
{
 echo ($key2);
}
```

Comment: he does use $key in the loop. to move the files: move_uploaded_file($key, "image/" . $fileName);

Answer (score 1):

Try the below block of code

```
$fileName[] = $name .'_'. uniqid() . '.' . $fileData['extension'];
move_uploaded_file($key, "image/" . end($fileName));
copy("image/" . end($fileName), "image_thumbnail/" . end($fileName));
```